# How to describe the language of an automaton in plain English?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

How do I describe the following automaton in plain English?

The only thing that I can think about when explaining in plain English would be the states, alphabet, start, accepting state, but I think there is more to when explaining about automata. How do I answer that?

```
The states are as follows: Q = {q1, q2, q3, q4} 
The alphabet is as follows: Σ = {0,1} 
The start state is q1
The accepting state is q4
```

[image]

Comment: What words does the automaton accept?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, it would accept any strings that contain at least 101 (in this order).

Comment: Do you want to describe how the automaton works or just the language it accepts? By the way, the automaton also accepts 1001, so your description of the language in your above comment is not entirely accurate.

Comment: @frabala, I guess it would be both, but mainly the language it accepts. Yeah, it would accept 101, 1001, 11001, 010111, 00110011, there are a number of states that are accepted, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between describing the language accepted by an automaton and describing the automaton itself. There can be several different automata that accept the same language.

For the particular automaton you give, the language it accepts can be described in plain English as "the set of words that contain at least two 1's separated by at least one 0". However, this sentence does not clarify whether a 3rd occurrence of 1 should also be separated by at least one 0 from the previous (or next) 1. A better description could be: "the automaton accepts a word if that word has a substring that contains two 1's separated by at least one 0". I think, this way it is clearer that once we have found a substring of the form $10^{n+1}1$, we don't care about the rest of the string.

To describe the automaton, this would be my attempt:
The automaton starts in state q1, on which it stays as long as it reads 0 from the input string. Once it reads 1, it moves to state q2 on which it stays as long as it reads 1 from the input string. Once it reads 0, it moves to state q3, on which it stays as long as it reads 0 from the input string. Once it reads 1, it moves to the accepting state q4, on which it stays forever.

Comment: Thanks @frabala! I believe I understood now how to respond this one, makes sense! Thanks!